# Non-compactness of operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Consider a linear operator $T$ on the Hilbert Space $l^2$ given by
$$T(x_1,x_2,...)=(a_0x_1,a_1x_2,\cdots),$$
where the sequence $(a_n)$ is dense in $[0,1]$. I deduced that $T$ cannot be compact because there will exist a subsequence of $(a_n)$ which will converge to 1 and hence the operator will ultimately become the identity operator on $l^2$ which is not compact. Can someone please verify if my reasoning is right?

Comment: Its incorrect that the operator converges to the isentity operator. But the proof that the identity operator is noncompact might shield some light on proving the noncompactness of T.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide some other reasoning for its non-compactness?

Comment: How do you prove that the identity operator is noncompact?

Comment: Wait, is ot really $x_1$ for all terms?

Comment: Oh no, that is a typo. Thank you so much for pointing out.

Comment: The identity operator on the Hilbert space in non compact because Hilbert space is infinite dimensional.

Comment: I am not what you mean by "hence the operator will eventually become the identity operator". However, recall that for a Hilbert space the set of compact operators is precisely the closure of finite rank operators. Then use that there exists a subsequence of the $a_n$ s.t. $a_{n_k} \rightarrow 1$ to show that $T$ cannot be approximated by finite rank operators